# Where should I place a CSS reset file for an Expo/React Native project?

Tags: css, reactjs, react-native, expo

I have a React Native project scaffolded using Expo and want to perform a CSS reset. Where would I place such a file and would I need to connect it to anything?

My current project structure looks like this:
[image: project structure screenshot]